# Matlab - How to combine a struct and loop to reduce the number of operations?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, struct

I am performing operations on four cell arrays and want to simplify my code. For each of the cell arrays three calculations are the same. I tried to introduce a struct and a for-loop such that these operations are performed as iteration. However, the struct does not execute the commands accurately. As a result, fewer rows are erased and the result is different from the individual operations.

This is the example of a manual operation on one of the cell arrays:

```
%Importing and sorting QoL data
lr = tsv2cell('LifeRating.tsv');
lr(3:36,8) = lr(38:end,7);                             
lr(37:end,:) = [];
lr(:,[2:6,9:end]) = [];
lr = sortrows(lr(2:end,:),1);
lr = erase(lr,[" e", " b", " p"]); 
lr = standardizeMissing(lr,':');
lr = rmmissing(lr);`
```

In this part, the last three lines are operations that are performed for each cell array, and thus could be placed in a for-loop. The struct and loop that I implemented look like:

```
s.pop=pop; s.gdp=gdp; s.fp=fp; s.lr=lr; 

f=fieldnames(s);
for c=1:length(f)
    s.(f{c})=erase(s.(f{c}),[" e", " b", " p"]); 
    s.(f{c})=standardizeMissing(s.(f{c}),':');
    s.(f{c})=rmmissing(s.(f{c}));
end
```

I expected that the dimensions of the cell arrays after using the struct would be the same as using the operations separately. However, the for-loop does not seem to affect the dimensions. Anyone had an idea why this might not work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it a minimal example?

Comment: Do you realize that modifying `s.pop` doesn’t modify `pop`?

Comment: The other thought: you’re better off using a cell array instead of a struct: `s={pop,gdp,fp,lr}`, then loop over `s{i}`, then unpack with `[pop,gdp,fp,lr]=deal(s{:})`.